# Apply SLD to raster in postgis query

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sld

Is there a way to color a postgis raster using an SLD file?

For example, I want a node server to pull an SLD file from a geoserver instance. Then I want the node server to run a postgis query to retrieve a raster and save it as a png which I've done, but it's gray scale. Is there a way to feed the sld into the query somehow to get color?

I could possibly write a parser that converts the sld into the format needed by [ST_ColorMap](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_ColorMap.html), but I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Comment: I have never heard of ST_ColorMap, thanks for that, really useful. I find SLDs to be the most cumbersome and difficult things to work with. I would have thought writing a parser would be by far the best way to go.

Comment: why not have GeoServer fetch the raster and style it using the SLD and return the png - it is already designed to do that

Comment: @iant I really wanted to have geoserver do the work, but the short of it is that the rasters are dynamically computed and clipped using raster algebra on various geoserver raster layers and shapefiles. I'm guessing WPS should be my best friend for this, but I've ran into a lot of problems trying to do it that way so I'm dropping down a level to check the feasibility of doing it in postgis. Could I send the raster generated from postgis to geoserver and tell geoserver to style it?

Comment: GeoServer doesn't really care how the raster was formed but it sounds like you need a WPS to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up following @iants advice and solved this with WPS.

The workflow is to run the postgis query to retrieve the clipped (unstyled) raster and save it to disk as a tiff on a webserver. Then use a WPS ras:StyleCoverage request to apply the style like so (wpsrequest.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>ras:StyleCoverage</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://my_node_server/raster_to_style.tiff" method="GET"/>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>style</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/xml; subtype=sld/1.0.0"><![CDATA[
                    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
                        <NamedLayer>
                            <Name>leafout</Name>
                            <UserStyle>
                                <Name>leafout</Name>
                                <Title>Day leaf index  reached</Title>
                                <FeatureTypeStyle>
                                    <Rule>
                                        <RasterSymbolizer>
                                            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
                                            <ColorMap>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="-9999" opacity="0.0" label=""/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="1"     label="Jan 1"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#B6DA00" quantity="15"    label="Jan 15"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#6DB600" quantity="32"    label="Feb 1"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#249200" quantity="46"    label="Feb 15"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#0A8019" quantity="60"    label="Mar 1"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#328180" quantity="74"    label="Mar 15"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#4682B4" quantity="91"    label="Apr 1"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#4764A8" quantity="105"   label="Apr 15"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#491E8D" quantity="121"   label="May 1"/>
                                                <ColorMapEntry color="#6A287E" quantity="135"     label="May 15"/>
                                            </ColorMap>
                                        </RasterSymbolizer>
                                    </Rule>
                                </FeatureTypeStyle>
                            </UserStyle>
                        </NamedLayer>
                    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
                    ]]>
                </wps:ComplexData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
            <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
```

The request can be ran via a curl post to save the stylized raster:

```
curl "http://user:password@geoserverInstance.org/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=execute" -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "@wpsrequest.xml" > styled_raster.tiff
```